# Kony : Not able to select base SDK version for Xcode 7.2 in kony studio preferences

Tags: temenos-quantum

I have updated my Xcode to 7.2 and I am trying to change my kony studio settings for the builds to automatically open in Xcode 7.2. However I am not able to select the base sdk version , simulator version etc as it is disabled in studio.

Please see the attached screens shot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Kony studio, from install new updates, post which it would support to select the base sdk

for mac os x. 
http://download.kony.com/studio/65/hotfixmacsite.xml